# Link is not working in dropdown-toggle

Tags: hyperlink, dropdown

[Link is not working in dropdown-toggle button in nav bar (Header menu), when i click dropdown list is working but the link is not working. The link is "Product.html" but its not go to the product page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8FOb.png)

```
<a href="product.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="product">Product<span class="fa fa-angle-down dropdown-arrow"></span></span></a>
```

Comment: Maybe caused by having the extra closing `</span>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the extra closing `</span>` tag inside the `<a></a>` tag.

```
<a href="product.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="product">Product<span class="fa fa-angle-down dropdown-arrow"></span></a>
```